# @supports not being used in FF and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, less

I'm writing my CSS in Less and for some reason the @supports is not being displayed. Could it be a nesting issue?

```css
@supports(display: grid) {
    .two-up {
        @media screen and (min-width: @small-screen) {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LESS [code compiles ok](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40small-screen%3A%2010em%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40supports(display%3A%20grid)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.two-up%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40media%20screen%20and%20(min-width%3A%20%40small-screen)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20display%3A%20grid%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grid-template-columns%3A%201fr%201fr%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

It works in both Chrome and Firefox:
https://codepen.io/oslego/pen/KeQpgr

```css
@small-screen: 10em;

@supports(display: grid) {
    .two-up {
        @media screen and (min-width: @small-screen) {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: green;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="two-up"></div>
```

Perhaps you have additional code following that rule or competing with it in an unexpected way.